# Tomcat 404 Not Found error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

My web application runs fine with Eclipse & Tomcat on my desktop PC. When I uploaded the war file to the actual server, I wasn't able to access all the servlets with the following error message. Other JSP and HTML files had no problems.

```
The requested URL /HelloWorld/TryingServlet was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Comment: First of all it seems that you have an apache httpd fronting tomcat. I get that from your ErrorDocument error. Are you sure you are trying to access the correct URL?

Comment: What kind of host is it? Godaddy or something? On some hosts, webapp-specific servlets are only available by a specific additional prefix in URL, something like `/servlets`. Basically, you need to read its developer FAQ/guide or contact the hosting support for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this url:

```
http://YOUR_IP:8080/HelloWorld.war/TryingServlet
```

Replace `HelloWorld.war` with the actual name of your war file...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your production environment tomcat is being fronted by an apache httpd which does not forward requests to tomcat for urls of the form `/foobar` (without an extension). Apache doesn't know how to deal with those URLs and tries to serve them as static files from the disk. The files are not there so it tries to execute the 404 rule which is badly configured (the configured 404 file is itself missing as well - but that's another problem).

Solutions:

- Assign an extension to all your servlets and specify that to apache. E.g `.do` (like struts does) so your servlet becomes `/foobar.do`. You'll then need to ask your sysadmin to specify that `*.do` goes to tomcat.
- Ask your sysadmin to configure apache to send all requests to tomcat apart of those for static files. E.g `*.jpg`, `*.png`, `*.css`, `*.js` etc