# Spring app returns 404 for all URL requests (except /) on third party app (works fine on localhost)

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404, web.xml

In my Spring app, I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public String goHome(ModelMap map){
    map.addAttribute("content", "home.jsp");
    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "register")
public String getRegisterPage(ModelMap map){
    map.addAttribute("content", "register.jsp");
    return "index";
}
```

On localhost, I can access them as **localhost:8080** and **localhost:8080/register** respectively. But when I deploy them on third party server, **domain.com** works fine but **domain.com/register** (and every other links other than domain.com) result in a 404.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /register was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Note:
- Both localhost and domain.com run on Tomcat 5.5 and has Servlet version 2.4
- I even changed RequestMapping value to **value="/register"** but nothing changed

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Adsense</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.adsense.connection.MySqlDBPooling</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Anything in the server logs with DEBUG logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer here: [Tomcat 404 Not Found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957217/tomcat-404-not-found-error)

> The problem is that in the production environment tomcat is being
>   fronted by an apache httpd which does not forward requests to tomcat
>   for urls of the form /foobar (without an extension). Apache doesn't
>   know how to deal with those URLs and tries to serve them as static
>   files from the disk. The files are not there so it tries to execute
>   the 404 rule which is badly configured (the configured 404 file is
>   itself missing as well - but that's another problem).
>
> Solutions:
>
> Assign an extension to all your servlets and specify that to apache.
>   E.g .do (like struts does) so your servlet becomes /foobar.do. You'll
>   then need to ask your sysadmin to specify that *.do goes to tomcat.
>   Ask your sysadmin to configure apache to send all requests to tomcat
>   apart of those for static files. E.g *.jpg, *.png, *.css, *.js etc

In my case, it worked fine with urls like /register.do :)